# How to convert c# console to Powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell, console-application

I am trying to convert the following c# console app to powershell script. So far the converted power-shell is stuck on ExtractCabFiles line. Did I miss anything in the converted code? Both are attached as I know it may help.

here is console code

```
  MethodInfo extractCab = typeof (SPSolutionLanguagePack).GetMethod("ExtractCabFiles",
                                    BindingFlags.Default |
                                    BindingFlags.Static |
                                    BindingFlags.NonPublic);

  //extract the wsp files to the temp folder
  extractCab.Invoke(null, newobject[] {Path.GetFullPath(filesFolder), Path.GetFullPath(solutionName)});
```

And here is the converted code

```
MethodInfo $extractCab = typeof (SPSolutionLanguagePack).GetMethod("ExtractCabFiles",
                                    BindingFlags.Default |
                                    BindingFlags.Static |
                                    BindingFlags.NonPublic);

#extract the wsp files to the temp folder
$extractCab.Invoke(null, newobject[] {Path.GetFullPath($filesFolder), Path.GetFullPath($solutionName)});
```

Comment: I tried my best to post this ad so I wont get negative mark. What should I do more? I will happy to modify it.

Comment: So you want to know how to access the `private static ExtractCabFiles(string folder, string solution)` method of `SPSolutionLanguagePack` from PowerShell?

Comment: http://csharpening.net/?p=491

Comment: Answer is Yes to Jodress

Comment: You don't really have to rewrite your c# stuff to make it work in Powershell: http://netpl.blogspot.com/2012/05/easy-way-to-become-powershell.html

Answer (score 0):

Your powershell syntax is incorrect in a few places.  You want this:

```
# you will need to specify the FULL namespace-qualified type name for SPSolutionLanguagePack, I don't know what that is from your post
$extractCab = [SPSolutionLanguagePack].GetMethod("ExtractCabFiles", [Reflection.BindingFlags] 'Default, Static, NonPublic')

#extract the wsp files to the temp folder
$extractCab.Invoke($null, @( [IO.Path]::GetFullPath($filesFolder), [IO.Path]::GetFullPath($solutionName)))
```